# Is it possible to not let a process run at 100% processor capacity using nice or other command?

Tags: cpu, macos, nice

If it is a cryptocoin mining program called `minerd`, can the command

```
nice -n -20 ./minerd ...
```

make the program run at the lowest priority? But can it let it run at 80% or 50% of the processor's full capacity so that the computer won't become overheated?

Comment: No priority only affects what thread runs (not whether a thread runs or nothing runs). Also `nice`ness is not priority. It is a bit more subtle than that, and `-20` is un-`nice`, this equates (sort of: did I say it is more subtle) to a high priority. Did you notice that you don't normally have permission to do nice of -20.

Answer (score 1):

Linux:

- cpulimit https://github.com/opsengine/cpulimit
- cgroups limit CPU: https://www.google.com/search?q=cgroups+limit+CPU
- systemd CPUQuota: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html

MacOS:

- AppPolice  (available via homebrew): https://github.com/AppPolice/AppPolice
- CPUThrottle: http://www.willnolan.com/cputhrottle/cputhrottle.html

Answer (score 1):

`nice` won't prevent a process from using 100% of the CPU. It only imposes a lower priority relative to other processes.

If you are afraid of overheating, one solution is to underclock the CPU.

A software solution to limit the process' CPU usage is the `cgroups` feature of *bandwidth* . See the [manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html).

Comment: if it is a Mac, then `cgroups` won't work?

Comment: Sorry, I keep forgetting that the world is larger than Linux. Indeed, `cgroups` is a Linux feature. There might be equivalent tools in MacOS.